# HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure .NET 5

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-core, server-error

I have a web project written in .NET 5. When I upload the project to my own server, I get the following error. I tried different solutions for the error but none of them worked. I enabled stdout logging in the Web Config file, but although there are stdout files, there is no text in it.But im also

I can connect to the server and run the project with the dotnet command. but I can't run it on the site.

[image]

In the screenshots below; you can find the error, NET versions installed on my server, my publish settings and webconfig file.

My Server: Windows Server 2019 x64
IIS Versiyon : 10
Project Target Framework : net5.0

My Webconfig file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ApplicationName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
   <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Error:
[image: Error]

Dotnet Runtimes List:

[image: Dotnet Runtimes List]

Project Publish Settings

[image: Publish Settings]

Comment: [Try this, and tell me the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J51el.jpg)

Comment: [If the link above not works, please follow the steps to check and update the question later.](https://docs.lacunasoftware.com/en-us/articles/amplia/on-premises/windows/troubleshoot/startup-errors.html)

Comment: First of all thank you for answer. Then i dont have "Remove additional files at destination" option as you can see: https://ibb.co/18tDRQP i tried x64 publish anyway but error still continue. When I looked at the server logs, I found a log like the one below. `Application '/LM/W3SVC/11/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomain.domain.com\' failed to start process with commandline 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomain.domain.com\EnthalpyWeb.exe ' at stage 'PostStartCheck', ErrorCode = '0x8027025b', assigned port 32199, retryCounter '0'.`

Comment: The setting in your pic is same as  "Remove additional files at destination". I am waiting for your update.

Comment: Could you share the structre of your publish? Let me check all the publish files.

Comment: You can see publish file structure with this link : https://docdro.id/yC9mj9o also im tried remove files option but error still continue. server log is same `Application '/LM/W3SVC/11/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomain.domain.com\' failed to start process with commandline 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomain.domain.com\EnthalpyWeb.exe ' at stage 'PostStartCheck', ErrorCode = '0x8027025b', assigned port 47629, retryCounter '0'.`

Comment: <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomain.domain.com\EnthalpyWeb.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true"  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"" hostingModel="InProcess"/>

Comment: Try this, I am still investigating the issue, and be patient.

Comment: If the setting not work, you could try to [set the ASPNETCORE_PORT environment variable](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9151).

Comment: I also need your code in program.cs to check some configurations about IIS.

Comment: Im tried add hostingModel inprocess section to webconfig but error is changed to HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252533/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-murateksiolu).